# EF Eager loading. How to retrieve just first element of related collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

I'm trying to eager load just first record of the related collection by this query:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SparePart>> GetFront()
  {
     return await _db.SparePart.Include(x => x.Photos.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x => x.Price).Take(12).AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync();
  }
```

but I got error `The Include path expression must reference the navigation property defined in the type` this look strange for me as I have this navigation property in related entity:

```
public partial class Photo
    {
        ...
        public int SparePartId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SparePartId")]
        public virtual SparePart SparePart { get; set; }
    }
```

Same as in parent entity:
public partial class SparePart

```
{
    public SparePart()
    {
        Photos = new HashSet<Photo>();
    }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The exception message is telling you that it expects expression referring to **property**, not `FirstOrDefault()` **method**. Eager loading does not support filtering, you must use [Expicit Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2) - see **Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities** section